# Issue with using Git Push in Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 on Mac M1 "Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server"

Tags: android, git, macos, android-studio, push

I am attempting to push my code onto my github account after sharing project repository. The repository is created but I get an error when I attempt to push:

> Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server

> error: unable to read askpass response from
> '/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2021.2/tmp/intellij-git-askpass-local.sh'
> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not
> configured

I have enabled Use Credential Helper under the git settings of Android Studio and I invalidated caches but neither of these steps seemed to work. I have also used the commands:

```
git --config --global user.email "xxx@gmail.com"
git --config --global user.name "xxx"
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this or where I could look to find more information?

Comment: The `--global` settings you're changing here have nothing to do with *authentication and credentials*, so don't do that. The problem is entirely with the chosen credential helper. You can switch to some other credential helper, or try to get assistance from JetBrains (who are the suppliers of this particular credential-helper).

Comment: A Git *credential helper* is a program (usually not distributed with Git, but rather from some third party) that is responsible for collecting and maintaining user names and passwords for `https://` connections. You can completely bypass the use of credential helpers by using `ssh://` connections and ssh *instead of* https, provided that there's no constraint that forces you to use https only.