# Android Studio fails to push to GitHub

Tags: android-studio, github

(I am aware of prior threads, this seems to be a new problem)
I upgraded Android Studio to 2021.2.1 patch 1 a couple of weeks ago.
Since then, communication with GitHub is flaky:

I cannot git push; I have to close the SDK, get back in, and then -- sometimes -- it works. Error message I get:

```
error: unable to read askpass response from 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2\tmp\intellij-git-askpass-local.sh'
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory
```

Git > Show Git Log -- shows 1 line of commit from 2 months ago, doesn't see anything.

Tried generating a new token (with access to EVERYTHING) -- no sugar.

Until I upgraded everything worked wonderfully.
Anyone knows what's going on?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That was [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72993556/6309) [before](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/233123296), with as a [(bad) workround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71576963/6309) embedding [the token in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70920900/6309).

Another workaround would to try and use an SSH URL instead of an HTTPS one (which involved the Git credential helper used for providing HTTPS credentials)

As reported by the [OP Yanay Lehavi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10231852/yanay-lehavi) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73095806/android-studio-fails-to-push-to-github/73095842?noredirect=1#comment129098560_73095842), a `git config --global --unset credential.helper` also avoid said credential helper.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The "git config --global --unset credential.helper" works too, but man, come on.... I'm hoping someone from the IntelliJ team monitors this thread...

Comment: @YanayLehavi Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.